# REACT- How do I refactor my code to avoid mulitple declaration of variable (20 in total)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I optimize/ factor my code. I have two cases 'exist' and 'new',depending on this value I made a different display.  At the beginning I've just create a general value called `user`, `pwd` ... (18 more) but the issue was that when I fill a field (user for example) for case 'exist' then the field 'user' is filled too - for the other case (i.e new) although they should not be the same.

Is there a way to factor my code please ?

```
export default function Choice() {

    const [existUser, setExistUser] = useState("");
    const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState("");
    const [existPwd, setPwd] = useState("");
    const [newPwd, setPwd] = useState("");
    // There are 20 in total with the exact same pattern (exist and new)
    ...
    let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            let res = await fetch("", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    existUser: existUser,
                    ...
                }),
            });
            let resJson = await res.json();
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setExistUser("");
               ...
    setRadio(false)
    message("Success")
} else {
    setMessage("Error");
}
        } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
    };


return (
    < >
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="radio" value='exist' onChange={(e) => setRadio(e.target.value)} checked={radio === 'exist'} />
            <input type="radio" value='new' onChange={(e) => setRadio(e.target.value)} checked={radio === 'new'} />
        </form>
        {(radio === 'exist') ?
            (
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <label >
                            User:
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={existUser}
                                placeholder="User"
                                onChange={(e) => setExistUser(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </label>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
            :
            ('')
        }

        {
            (radio === 'new') ?
                (<div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            //Other inputs with the exct same pattren as before - newUser...
                        <inputs .../>
                    </form>
                </div>
                )
                :
                ('')
        }

        {(radio === ('exist')) ?
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        // Exact same inputs to display as radio==='new' (above)
                </form >
            </div>
            :
            ('')
        }

    </>
)
}
```

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/first-page-with-dynamic-field-e3ofjj?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

You could create two [contexts](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) with the  states you need: `user`, `pwd`, etc. The repeated structure could be encapsulated with a factory.

[Full example on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/first-page-with-dynamic-field-forked-mwl86y?file=/src/App.js), but you will get something like this:

```
// FormContext.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// the two contexts you need
export const NewFormContext = React.createContext();
export const ExistFormContext = React.createContext();

// the factory that creates a provider with the same states
// but, independent and linked to different contexts
const makeFormProvider = (FormContext) => ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState("");
  
  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{pwd,user, setUser, setPwd}}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const NewFormProvider = makeFormProvider(NewFormContext);
export const ExistFormProvider = makeFormProvider(ExistFormContext);
```

Then, inside the component in which you should render the `Choice.jsx` - thats `App.jsx` in my case -  after you provide the contexts to your component

```
  // App.jsx
  <NewFormProvider>
    <ExistFormProvider>
      <Choice />
    </ExistFormProvider>
  </NewFormProvider>
```

Just consume them

```
// Choice.jsx
const newForm = useContext(NewFormContext)
const existForm = useContext(ExistFormContext)

const handleSubmit = () => {
  // handle it here
}

return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" id="new-user" value={newForm.user} onChange={(e) => newForm.setUser(e.target.value)} />
          <input type="text" id="exist-user" value={existForm.user} onChange={(e) => existForm.setUser(e.target.value)}/>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
```

P.S.: Take care when reusing code like this. Be sure these two forms will change for the same reason, respecting the [SRP](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html). If they won't, just use two separate structures from the beginning.

Comment: I've put your first code in a file called : `makeFormProvider.jsx` ,the second code you put it where ? And the last code I put it in my `Choice` component as you said

Comment: I put the Second code on my `App.jsx`, the direct parent of `Choice.jsx`

Comment: I have editted the answer adding the files I used

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem working for me, I got a blank page. Btw, I use handleSubmit, I don't see where you're using it

Comment: do you have any errors on your console?

Comment: oh, i did not put all the <form> structure with handle submit and stuff because i thought it was irrelevant for the example, but i'll add it

Comment: HI, I've edited my question and posting my link code. If you can post your codes in a sandbox link please because for now, it's not working

Comment: for sure! you  will put there and link here

Comment: here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/first-page-with-dynamic-field-forked-mwl86y?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are mainly 2 ways to refactor this many-states-problem

1. use `object` state instead of single `string` state
2. use custom hook to make two states seems one

**1. use `object` state instead of single `string` state**

```js
const [radio, setRadio] = useState("");
const [existValues, setExist] = useState({});
const [newValues, setNew] = useState({});
```

**2. use custom hook to make two states seems one (affected by context)**

```js
let [user, setUser] = useChoicValue();
let [pwd, setPwd] = useChoicValue();
```

for this two main way, each you can make other optimize, for example, bring reusable codes for each subject into a template, then reuse the template with subject specific props, or mix some good points from these ways

**3. resusable subject template**

```js
const ExistOrNew = ({
  radio,
  name,
  existValue,
  newValue,
  updateExist,
  updateNew
}) => {
```

**4. use context to reduce prop drill**

```js
const ExistOrNew = ({
    radio,
    name,
    keyExist,
    keyNew
  }) => {
    let newCtx = useContext(NewCtx);
    let existCtx = useContext(ExistCtx);
```

**5. use a lib that's good at handle states**

things like https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

---

**So I made 4 example refactor**

1. use object state instead of string state + template: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dewdney-c2ypv4?file=/src/components/Refactor2Comps1.jsx
2. object + template + context: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dewdney-c2ypv4?file=/src/components/Refactor2Comps2.jsx
3. lib + template: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dewdney-c2ypv4?file=/src/components/RefactorLib.jsx
4. custom hook: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dewdney-c2ypv4?file=/src/components/RefactorHook.jsx:434-514

---

**and working codes here, try it yourself**
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dewdney-c2ypv4?file=/src/App.js

[image]